# calling python script from php with import module in it

Tags: php, python

I have a module ( Z:\development\pipeline\tom\maya\modules\getTicket ) imported in python script (which queries database and sends list on web interface) being called in a PHP script.

The Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import getTicket as serverSetup
import json

def main():
    var = []
    var.append("From Python :):)")
    print var
json.dumps(main())
```

php code :

```
putenv('PYTHONPATH=Z:/development/pipeline/tom/maya/modules');
```

This **import getTicket** line is giving an error (see below). Without this import it works fine.

Question is how do I import a python module in python script such that when this python script is run within a php script that it works alright.

error in apache_error.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tacticactivity.py", line 13, in <module>
    import getTicket as serverSetup
ImportError: No module named getTicket
```

Comment: Is there a `getTicket.py` file in Z:/development/pipeline/tom/maya/modules, or an `__init__.py` in Z:/development/pipeline/tom/maya/modules/getTicket/ ? Have you tried printing `sys.path` in the Python script?

Comment: getTicket.py is there. So is __init__.py. in ...maya/modules